# not able to create thumbnail(jpeg) from azure media storage?

Tags: c#, azure-media-services

I am trying to create thumbanil from azure storage after uploading a video,

so i have a xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Thumbnail Size="30%,*" Type="Jpeg" Filename="abc_1.jpg">
  <Time Value="0:3:19"/>
</Thumbnail>
```

and in my c# level cod i a  creating a job

```
 IAsset asset = CreateAssetAndUploadSingleFile(inputMediaFilePath,
                "My Video Thumbnail Input Asset",
                AssetCreationOptions.None);

            // Declare a new job.
            IJob job = _context.Jobs.Create("My Video Thumbnail Job");

            // Get a reference to Azure Media Video Thumbnails.
            string MediaProcessorName = "Azure Media Video Thumbnails";

            var processor = GetLatestMediaProcessorByName(MediaProcessorName);

            var ThumbnailConfig = File.ReadAllText("Thumbnail_Configuration.xml");

            // Create a task with the encoding details, using a string preset.
            ITask task = job.Tasks.AddNew("My Video Thumbnail Task",
                processor,
                configuration,
                TaskOptions.None);
```

but when i run the code i am getting error saying that xml is invalid, what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The code appears to be using an incorrect combination of the preset XML and the media processor. If you need to generate thumbnails at a specific timestamp, then change the media processor and the preset:

```
string MediaProcessorName = "Media Encoder Standard";
```

And in ThumbnailConfig, use the following JSON string:

```
{
  "Version": 1.0,
  "Codecs": [
    {
      "JpgLayers": [
        {
          "Quality": 90,
          "Type": "JpgLayer",
          "Width": "30%",
          "Height": "30%"
        }
      ],
      "Start": "00:03:19",
      "Step": "1",
      "Range": "1",
      "Type": "JpgImage"
    }
  ],
  "Outputs": [
    {
     "FileName": "abc_{Index}{Extension}",
      "Format": {
        "Type": "JpgFormat"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see other examples documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-dotnet-generate-thumbnail-with-mes).

Answer (score 0):

Can you also please share where you found documentation that referred to the following:

```
// Get a reference to Azure Media Video Thumbnails.
            string MediaProcessorName = "Azure Media Video Thumbnails";
```

I'd like to have any documentation that you found that referenced that removed.